# Error 423 while trying to create new event

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When I try to create a new event I receive error 423, which means that resource that is being accessed is locked, but when I try to create a new event via Graph Explorer there is no such problem.

I have `Calendars.ReadWrite` permission added. What can be the reason for such an error? How to check what resource is locked, and how to unlock it?

> E/global: CoreHttpProvider[sendRequestInternal] - 423Error during http request
>
> E/global: Throwable detail: com.microsoft.graph.core.ClientException: Error during http request

Comment: sorry for delay here. Can you provide the request-id of request that you get in the response from the service?

Comment: also, could you check that your access token has the  Calendars.ReadWrite scope in it using https://jwt.ms/ as per the docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example

The fact it works in Graph Explorer and not in your code usually is access tokens not containing correct tokens or that you are accessing a different calendar in a diff user mailbox to Graph Explorer.